# Get the list of ODBC data source names programmatically using Delphi

Tags: delphi, odbc, ado, delphi-2006

I saw several examples where the list of the source names were took from registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources). Is there any other way to get the list of ODBC data sources names?

I need to work only with Delphi standard components, so I can not use 3d party solutions.

Comment: What is the problem with read that registry location?

Comment: There isn't a problem with that. It's even simpler than accessing ODBC32.DLL. I'm asking how can I accomplish this in the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [SQLDataSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from ODBC32.DLL. For [example](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=107542).

Answer (score 1):

As @da-soft stated in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7676569/1339507), [SQLDataSources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldatasources-function) in ODBC32.DLL will do this. However, as the link they provided is no longer working, here's an actual example (adapted from Menno Avegaar's answer to [an old delphi groups post](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/ad/345347.html)):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

function SQLAllocEnv(var EnvironmentHandle: Pointer): SmallInt; stdcall; external 'odbc32.dll';
function SQLFreeEnv(EnvironmentHandle: Pointer): SmallInt; stdcall; external 'odbc32.dll';
function SQLDataSources(
  EnvironmentHandle: Pointer;
  Direction: Word;
  ServerName: PAnsiChar;
  BufferLength1: SmallInt;
  var NameLength1: SmallInt;
  Description: PAnsiChar;
  BufferLength2: SmallInt;
  var NameLength2: SmallInt): SmallInt; stdcall; external 'odbc32.dll';

const
  SQL_SUCCESS = 0;
  SQL_NO_DATA = 100;
  SQL_FETCH_NEXT = 1;
  SQL_FETCH_FIRST = 2;
  SQL_MAX_DSN_LENGTH = 32;
  SQL_MAX_OPTION_STRING_LENGTH = 256;

var
  EnvironmentHandle: Pointer;
  Buffer1: array[0..SQL_MAX_DSN_LENGTH] of AnsiChar;
  Buffer2: array[0..SQL_MAX_OPTION_STRING_LENGTH] of AnsiChar;
  Len1, Len2: SmallInt;
  ServerName, Description: String;
begin
  if SQLAllocEnv(EnvironmentHandle) = SQL_SUCCESS then
  begin
    try
      if SQLDataSources(
        EnvironmentHandle,
        SQL_FETCH_FIRST,
        Buffer1,
        SizeOf(Buffer1),
        Len1,
        Buffer2,
        SizeOf(Buffer2),
        Len2) = SQL_SUCCESS then
      repeat
        SetString(ServerName, Buffer1, Len1);   
        SetString(Description, Buffer2, Len2);
        Writeln('Name:'+ServerName);
        Writeln('Description:'+Description);
        Writeln('');
      until SQLDataSources(
        EnvironmentHandle,
        SQL_FETCH_NEXT,
        Buffer1,
        SizeOf(Buffer1),
        Len1,
        Buffer2,
        SizeOf(Buffer2),
        Len2) = SQL_NO_DATA;
    finally
      SQLFreeEnv(EnvironmentHandle);
    end;
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```